# Regex to replace &nbsp with &nbsp;

Tags: regex

I need to replace `&nbsp` with `&nbsp;` but `&nbsp;` with `&nbsp;`
My regex is `&nbsp([^;])`

my replacement is `&nbsp;`

My code is replacing

```
<pre><code>
<ul><b> </b>&nbsp</ul>
<tr valign="top"><td width="144">&nbsp;United Kingdom</td><td width="144">&nbsp;Pound</td><td width="144">&nbsp;Pence</td></tr></pre></code>
```

with

```
<pre><code>
<ul><b> </b>&nbsp;/ul>
<tr valign="top"><td width="144">&nbsp;United Kingdom</td><td width="144">&nbsp;Pound</td><td width="144">&nbsp;Pence</td></tr>
```

It is removing the < tag in `</ul></pre></code>`

Any help?

Comment: Which language or tool you are using?

Comment: No need for RegEx. This can be done in every language by a simple string replace function.

Answer (score 2):

try the regex with a lookahead

```
(&nbsp)(?!;)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use lookaround

```
(?<=&nbsp)(?=[^;])
```

**OR**

```
(?<=&nbsp)(?!;)
```

replace it with `;`

Comment: Certainly the most interesting answer. But still, for each character you're coming back to the 5th before, so one should not be searching for performance :)

Answer (score 0):

It would probably be better to capture the non ; character and adding ; infront of it.

Search string:

```
(&nbsp)([^;])
```

Replace string:

```
\1;\2
```